# How to find out first product item client purchased whose bought specific products?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a query to locate a group of clients whose purchased specific 2 product categories, at the same time, getting the information of first transaction date and first item they purchased. Since I used group by function, I could only get customer id but not first item purchase due to the nature of group by. Any thoughts to solve this problem?

What I have are transaction tables(t), customer_id tables(c) and product tables(p). Mine is SQL server 2008.

**Update**

```
SELECT t.customer_id
  ,t.product_category
  ,MIN(t.transaction_date) AS FIRST_TRANSACTION_DATE
  ,SUM(t.quantity) AS TOTAL_QTY
  ,SUM(t.sales) AS TOTAL_SALES
FROM transaction t
WHERE t.product_category IN ('VEGETABLES', 'FRUITS')
  AND t.transaction_date BETWEEN '2020/01/01' AND '2022/09/30'
GROUP BY t.customer_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.product_category) = 2
```

```
**Customer_id**  **transaction_date** **product_category**  **quantity** **sales**
1                   2022-05-30           VEGETABLES             1             100
1                   2022-08-30           VEGETABLES             1             100
2                   2022-07-30           VEGETABLES             1             100
2                   2022-07-30           FRUITS                 1             50
2                   2022-07-30           VEGETABLES             2             200
3                   2022-07-30           VEGETABLES             3             300
3                   2022-08-01           FRUITS                 1             50
3                   2022-08-05           FRUITS                 1             50
4                   2022-08-07           FRUITS                 1             50
4                   2022-09-05           FRUITS                 2             100
```

In the above, what I want to show after executing the SQL query is

```
**Customer_id**  **FIRST_TRANSACTION_DATE** **first_product_category** **TOTAL_QUANTITY** **TOTAL_SALES**
2                   2022-07-30                VEGETABLES, FRUITS             4             350
3                   2022-07-30                VEGETABLES                    5             400
```

Customer_id 1 and 4 will not be shown as they only purchased either vegetables or fruits but not both

Comment: If you copied this directly from your original query you will probably want to change TRANSACTION DATE to t.transaction_date in your WHERE clause.

Comment: @GonePhishing
Thank you and updated. Yet, the issue is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check now, BTW need find logic with `product_category`

```
    select CustomerId, transaction_date, product_category, quantity, sales
        from(
        select CustomerId, transaction_date, product_category , sum(quantity) over(partition by CustomerId ) as quantity , sum(sales) over(partition by CustomerId ) as sales, row_number() over(partition by CustomerId order by transaction_date ASC) rn  
        from(
        select CustomerId, transaction_date, product_category, quantity, sales 
        from tablee t
        where  (product_category = 'FRUITS' and
         EXISTS (select CustomerId
                      from tablee tt
                      where product_category = 'VEGETABLES'
                      and t.CustomerId = tt.CustomerId)) OR
                (product_category = 'VEGETABLES' and
         EXISTS (select CustomerId
                      from tablee tt
                      where product_category = 'FRUITS'
                      and t.CustomerId = tt.CustomerId)))x)over_all
                      where rn = 1;
```

HERE is [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d5fef2/59)

Comment: is this INNER JOIN product p ON t.product_category and p.product_category correct?

Comment: @Nickname_used
Error message: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE' by using the below codes. As 2 WHERES appeared


`SELECT *
FROM (SELECT t.customer_id, p.product_item, row_number() partition by t.customer_id order by t.transaction_date ASC) as rn
FROM transaction t INNER JOIN product p ON t.product_category and p.product_category
WHERE t.transaction_date BETWEEN '2020/01/01' AND '2022/09/30'
AND t.product_category IN ('VEGETABLES', 'FRUITS')
AND (t.product_category = 2) WHERE rn = 1`

Comment: In my answer are two select statments first SELECT as x, i think you incorrectly copy my code. because in your comment i didnt see `...... transaction_date BETWEEN '2020/01/01' AND '2022/09/30'` and then `)x`@Miss55

Comment: It works. However, with the codes above, result is now showing that customers who bought Vegetables or Fruits instead of customers who bought both Vegetables and fruits @Nickname_used

Comment: i need to see your data example

Comment: Update the data example above. Thank you for your help @Nickname_used

Comment: why costumer_id = 2 have quantity 2 and sales 150 ? if  2022-07-30 day sold 4 quantity and for 350

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Modified the data. Total quantity and Total sales should be showing the sum of the quantity / sales of the customer_id in the tracking period. 
Whereas, the first_product_category refers to the product category purchased during first transaction date.
@Nickname_used

Comment: @Miss55 check now i edited answer